# Composite key containing two items of same type

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I spent some time searching, but didn't receive a satisfactory result.

My classes are:

```
Listener, ListenerPK
Actuator, ActuatorPK
DeviceState, DeviceStatePK
```

where ListenerPK contains an instance of DeviceStatePK and a String, and ActuatorPK contains an instance of ListenerPK and an instance of DeviceStatePK.

So Actuator contains a Listener and a DeviceState (both marked @Id, @ManyToOne), Listener contains a DeviceState and a String (@Id, @ManyToOne).

My problem is that in JPA, when I do this I get an exception as follows:

Exception Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field XXX.  Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only.

I don't see where the multiple writable mappings exist. Am I obviously going wrong here?

Comment: Want to show your entities and code?  What is the field in the exception and how do you have it mapped?  What does your table structure look like?  My guess is that you have the Actuator->devicestate mapped multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this, I wanted to say that I'm using a join table. I'm not sure what was causing the original errors, but I think it was that JPA was assuming that my two entities of the same type were in fact the same entity.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, Actuator's table contains a single foreign key but you have it mapped to both the Listener and the DeviceState entities.  Since Listener's pk already includes a reference to DeviceState, the object model could be represented such that Actuator references a Listener which references a DeviceState.  ActuatorPK isn't needed; Actuator can just use the ListenerPK class as its primary key, since both tables just use the DeviceStatePK and String as their primary key.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ListenerPK.class)
public class Actuator {
  @Id
  @OneToOne
  Listener listener;
  ..
}
@Entity
@IdClass(ListenerPK.class)
public class Listener{
  @Id
  @ManyToOne
  DeviceState deviceState;
  @Id
  String stringId;
  ..
}
```

You would get a DeviceState associated to a Actuator through its Listener reference.  Alternatively you could map it as read-only within Actuator:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ListenerPK.class)
public class Actuator {
  @Id
  @OneToOne
  Listener listener;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="deviceState_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
  DeviceState deviceState;
  ..
}
```

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/DerivedIdentifiers